# IF Function with too many arguments

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

I want to apply this formula

```
=IF(A2= "", "", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "Brand"), "Brand", 
 if(regexmatch(A2, "Loans"), "Loans" , 
 if(regexmatch(A2, "Cards"), "Credit Cards", 
 if(A2, "Generic"),"Generic", 
 if(REGEXMATCH(A2, "Generic"), "Generic", "Non-brand")))))
```

But it has more than 3 arguments.

Any idea on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A2<>"", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "Brand"), "Brand", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "Loans"), "Loans" , 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "Cards"), "Credit Cards", 
 IF(A2="Generic", "Generic", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2, "Generic"), "Generic", "Non-brand"))))), )
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing more that one thing, you may want to try the [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) functions. This evaluates multiple conditions and returns a value that corresponds to the first true condition.